# Why is DNS not working on one domain, but is on another?

Tags: dns, hosting, cpanel, nameservers

I have the following 2 websites on the same hosting account and using the same DNS settings:

http://www.supadupawebdesign.co.uk (not working)

http://www.jukeboxstar.com (working)

Recently my hosting's domain name expired, but has now been renewed. I expected downtime because of this, but now that the host has renewed, I can't understand why one works and one doesn't. I tried doing some DNS checking tools but i'm still none the wiser as to why only one of them works.

Furthermore, they both work from my home, but not from anywhere else and all other tools I check online say it's down.

What is wrong with the supadupa domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the fact that the server that you have pointed your domain name to does not respond properly. That most likely mean that the DNS zone for this domain name does not exist or is broken.

When you perform a DNS lookup, what you get is:

> > Searching for supadupawebdesign.co.uk. A record at C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
> >     [192.33.4.12] ...took 1 ms Searching for supadupawebdesign.co.uk. A
> >     record at dns4.nic.uk. [43.230.48.1] ...took 14 ms Searching for
> >     cl2.owphosting.com. A record at F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [192.5.5.241]
> >     ...took 1 ms Searching for cl2.owphosting.com. A record at
> >     e.gtld-servers.net. [192.12.94.30] ...took 1 ms Searching for
> >     cl2.owphosting.com. A record at dns3.name-services.com. [162.88.61.39]
> >     ...took 3 ms Searching for supadupawebdesign.co.uk. A record at
> >     cl2.owphosting.com. [69.64.147.37] Query timed out (interrupted after
> >     2,000 milliseconds) Retrying... Searching for cl1.owphosting.com. A
> >     record at M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. [202.12.27.33] ...took 24 ms Searching
> >     for cl1.owphosting.com. A record at a.gtld-servers.net. [192.5.6.30]
> >     ...took 14 ms Searching for cl1.owphosting.com. A record at
> >     dns2.name-services.com. [162.88.60.23] ...took 0 ms Searching for
> >     supadupawebdesign.co.uk. A record at cl1.owphosting.com.
> >     [69.64.147.37] Query timed out (interrupted after 2,003 milliseconds)
> >     Retrying... Searching for supadupawebdesign.co.uk. A record at
> >     cl2.owphosting.com. [69.64.147.37] Query timed out (interrupted after
> >     2,002 milliseconds) Retrying... Searching for supadupawebdesign.co.uk.
> >     A record at cl1.owphosting.com. [69.64.147.37]
>
> **Query timed out (interrupted after 2,003 milliseconds) None of the nameservers responded correctly.**

Whereas the same server responds correctly for the other domain name.
That is why since I can see that you are using a cPanel server, you should make sure that this domain name is properly added to your account. If it is an addon domain, try to remove it and add it again. If there is some corrupted record in the DNS configuration you will either fix it this way, or if it does not allow you to add the domain again, you should contact the host so that they can check their DNS zone for this domain.

Comment: In this case, the domain in question is the 'main domain' on the cPanel hosting account. I have access to a 'Zone Editor'. Perhaps some tweaking could fix this.

Comment: If it is the primary domain name, the chance of the DNS zone being corrupted still exists. The nameservers do not respond with an A record for this domain name, so you should check if there is a valid A record set in the Zone editor- it should point to 45.35.57.16 as I can see. If the A record is present make sure that it is just 1 and there are no CNAMES for this domain name. If all the above is set properly you should call the host because sometimes when some outages appear on a cPanel server, the Zones may get broken and they are the ones who can fix that is you do not have WHM access.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at the A record (and a CNAME record) exists for both domains. I wonder if remove the A record and re-adding it might fix it? Another option, perhaps I setup the DNS records my registrar's DNS?

Comment: You cannot have a cname and an A record for the same domain name. Remove the CNAME for supadupawebdesign.co.uk and make sure that you have only an A record with the IP of the hosting server and that should do the trick. The other option is still possible if the zone is not broken-point the domain name to the registrar's nameservers and from their panel set an A record to the server IP ( if they allow that because some registrars do not allow you to set A records through them)

Comment: My apologies, the CNAME was for 'www....' I'll try setting up the whole thing on my registrar and see.